# How to randomize pen color in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic I have the code for the pen to color the line in black, I need it to be randomized.
This Pen needs to be randomized color: g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x * y, 50, x * y, 250)

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        Dim x, y As Integer
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(1350, 750)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 100, 1500, 100)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 200, 1500, 200)
        y = 20
        For x = 1 To 150
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x * y, 50, x * y, 250)
        Next x
        PictureBox1.Image = bmp
End Sub
```

Comment: If it's RGB format, couldn't you just create random numbers between 0 and 255 for each (R, G & B)? Otherwise you may need to give some more info.

Comment: What have you already tried?  How did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pens aren't an enum so the only way to enumerate the Pens class would probably be via reflection. Consider creating something that randomizes based on a Color's RGB:

```
Dim rng as New Random()
For x = 1 To 150
  Using pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(rng.Next(256), rng.Next(256), rng.Next(256)))
    g.DrawLine(pen, x * y, 50, x * y, 250)
  End Using
Next x
```

If you truly only want pens that use a system defined color name like AliceBlue or AntiqueWhite you might need to use `Color.FromKnownColor(CType(rng.Next(28, 168),KnownColor))`